# Facebook Privacy Permissions Design

Tags: database, database-design, facebook, permissions

Does anyone know the general layout of how facebook's privacy permissions system works (database)? I've been trying to figure out how they manage to have such a complex set of rules be applied to various content on their site, yet it remains fast. How are they doing that?

Comment: Note, regarding the bounty, I don't even care about Facebook specifically—just the various ways of implementing privacy permissions (abstractly) with similar levels of control to Facebook's.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122772/how-are-viewing-permissions-usually-implemented-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 1):

Lots of control flags?

Comment: And lots of fast memory. And not caring too, too much about accuracy ;)